# Placing 4 servlets in one project

Tags: java, servlets

i dont know how to place many servlets in one project. Am I supposed to create seperate web.xml file for each one? I have 4 html files named index.html,index1.html,index2.html and index3.html
Thanks beforehand

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     

 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"    
  version="3.0">
 <display-name>WM2_as03</display-name>


 <servlet>
<servlet-name>form</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.ccc.Task3</servlet-class>

 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>form</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>newtask</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.ccc.Task3</servlet-class>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>newtask</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/taskkk</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: No. In a single web xml you can place all of them

Comment: I should user <servlet> for each one?

Comment: Yes and it's mapping too. Look at examples on internet

Comment: I dont know what is a problem but when i do that url pattern doesnt work

Comment: can you post your web.xml

Comment: I added it on the post

Comment: It gives HTML 500-null error

Comment: what is the url.what is the web app name. Just giving the web.xml we cannot figure out the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead using web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>packageName.servletName</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/yourServletUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

you can use annotations since servlets 3.0.

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(name = "servletName", urlPatterns = { "/yourServletUrl" })
public class servletName extends HttpServlet {
```

It is easier and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Create 1 web.xml file and add multiple servlets :

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>path_to.Servlet1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/s1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>path_to.Servlet2</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/s2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```